# How to make the root element mandatory in JSONSchema

Tags: jsonschema

I have the below JSONSchema, I want the root tag envelope to be mandatory.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
   {
  "id": "envelope",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "tittle": "Root schema",
  "description": "Root schema for all services",
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "metadata",
    "data"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The meta data of the data field",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "sourceSystem",
        "deliveryCount",
        "retryPeriod",
        "correlationId"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sourceSystem": {
          "description": "The source System ",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "deliveryCount": {
          "description": "Number of times the request tried",
          "type": "number",
          "default": 0,
          "maxLength": 5
        },
        "retryPeriod": {
          "description": "Time set to retry",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "correlationId": {
          "description": "Unique id for reference",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "description": "The actual content",
      "type": "object"
    },
    "response": {
      "description": "Response",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The output is

```
{
    "metadata": {
      "sourceSystem": "",
      "deliveryCount": 1,
      "retryPeriod": 30,
      "correlationId": ""
    },
    "data": {}
}
```

expected output is

**{   "envelope" : {
    "metadata": {
      "sourceSystem": "",
      "deliveryCount": 1,
      "retryPeriod": 30,
      "correlationId": ""
    },
    "data": {}   } }**

Answer (score 1):

The `"id"` attribute does not define any root element, it is used for different purposes.

All you need to do is to define your root schema as an object with a single `"envelope"` property:

```
{
  "type" : "object"
  "properties" : {
    "envelope" : {
      // here comes your (current) schema
    }
  }
}
```